# Определить в какую категорию добавлять товар в бд php

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, opencart2.0

есть массив данных из прайса,в нем под $row_file[6] идет категория товара,надо определить к какой категории из сайта она относится и тогда присвоить id категории к товару который из прайса по этой категории.

```
название категории  id-категории
Бра (настенные)        18
Бра (настенные)  >  Классика, Модерн (Eurosvet) 45
Бра (настенные)  >  Оптима (Eurosvet)   75
Бра (настенные)  >  Хрусталь (Eurosvet) 46
Встраиваемые точечные светильники   24
```

И таких категорий много,надо пройтись по всем и если категория из прайса подходит к какой то категории из сайта,то делаем запрос в бд и записываем в таблицу этот товар к этой категории.(запрос в бд и добавление сам сделаю)мне бы разобраться как сделать поиск из того что у меня есть,есть название категории из прайса и есть категории из сайта.

Comment: И в чем проблема? Где ваш код в котором что-то не получается?

Comment: так в том то и проблема,я не знаю даже начать с чего))по этому моменту,могу скинуть код где я обрабатываю прайс,где делаю проверку есть ли товар такой в бд,где добавляю в таблицы продукта и дескрипшена,но что это даст?))мне надо разобраться с категориями и вот по ним ступор